# Automatically convert WPF TextBox input to All Caps?

Tags: wpf, textbox

How should I convert all  WPF TextBox input text into Caps?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My guess would be to set the [CharacterCasing property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.charactercasing.aspx) on the Textbox.

Answer (score 5):

I believe TextBox has a `CharacterCasing` property you can set to Upper

Answer (score 1):

Add something like that in your global styles in App.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">        
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper" />
</Style>
```

Comment: In a simple app if a style isn't defined this syntax works: <TextBox Name="TextBoxName" CharacterCasing="Upper"></TextBox>